# NotificationCompat.setLargeIcon(Bitmap) is not showing

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working with Notification. But the method `setLargeIcon(Bitmap)` did not work. This is my code snippet:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "chanel1103")
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_music_player))
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.noti_title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.noti_content));
            .setSubText(getString(R.string.noti_sub_text));

if (notificationManager != null) {
      notificationManager.notify(1, notificationCompatBuilder.build());
}
```

No matter I put **setLargeIcon** right before **setSmallIcon**, it still did not work. It only showed the **smallIcon** for both *small and largeIcon*. My large icon is a vector drawable

Comment: What device have you used for checking it?

Comment: @shmakova I am using Sony Xperia M5 dual, Android 5.1 (Lollipop)

Comment: Please provide the size of you large and small icons

Comment: My small icon is `android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm` which is android default bitmap (idk the exact width and height). My large icon is a vector drawable which has `width = 40dp` and `height = 40dp`

Answer (score 2):

If you use vector image resources you have to get bitmap like this:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

And then in your builder:

```
.setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(this, R.drawable.R.drawable.ic_music_player))
```

Answer (score 1):

you used vector drawable is show only small icon if large icon then set png or any large image that is show. but vector drawable icon show only small icon.

```
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(DbInsert.this, "chanel1103")
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a)) // set a png or jpg images
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm) //set vector drawable is work.
                    .setContentTitle("HHHHHHHHHHH")
                    .setContentText("GGGGGGGGGGGGG")
        .setSubText("DFGGG");

            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.notify(1, notificationCompatBuilder.build());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please rephrase your answer properly. It's very difficult to understand.

Comment: does this method support on. android 10? seems like not showing bitmap in large icon

Comment: I think what he meant was that you can only use vector drawables with `setSmallIcon` and not with `setLargeIcon`